# Is there a way to test if a computer's connection is firewalled?

Tags: p2p, firewall

I'm writing a piece of P2P software, which requires a direct connection to the Internet. It is decentralized, so there is no always-on server that it can contact with a request for the server to attempt to connect back to it in order to observe if the connection attempt arrives.

Is there a way to test the connection for firewall status?

I'm thinking in my dream land where wishes were horses, there would be some sort of 3rd-party, public, already existent servers to whom I could send some sort of simple command, and they would send a special ping back. Then I could simply listen to see if that arrives and know whether I'm behind a firewall.

Even if such a thing does not exist, are there any alternative routes available?

Comment: @freefallr It's a QT cross-platform app that will run on Linux, OS X, and Windows. Are you suggesting there are operating system hooks I can look for this information from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nantucket - does your service listen on UDP or TCP?

For UDP - what you are sort of describing is something the [STUN protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389) was designed for. It matches your definition of *"some sort of simple command, and they would send a special ping back"*

STUN is a very "ping like" (UDP) protocol for a server to echo back to a client what IP and port it sees the client as. The client can then use the response from the server and compare the result with what it thinks its locally enumerated IP address is. If the server's response matches the locally enumerated IP address, the client host can self determinte that it is directly connected to the Internet.  Otherwise, the client must assume it is behind a NAT - but for the majority of routers, you have just created a port mapping that can be used for other P2P connection scenarios.

Further, you can you use the [RESPONSE-PORT attribute](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5780#page-22) in the STUN binding request for the server to respond back to a different port.  This will effectively allow you to detect if you are firewalled or not.

TCP - this gets a little tricky. STUN can partially be used to determine if you are behind a NAT.  Or simply making an http request to whatismyip.com and parsing the result to see if there's a NAT. But it gets tricky, as there's no service on the internet that I know of that will test a TCP connection back to you.

With all the above in mind, the vast majority of broadband users are likely behind a NAT that also acts as a firewall. Either given by their ISP or their own wireless router device.  And even if they are not, most operating systems have some sort of minimal firewall to block unsolicited traffic. So it's very limiting to have a P2P client out there than can only work on direct connections.

With that said, on Windows (and likely others), you can program your app's install package can register with the Windows firewall so your it is not blocked.  But if you aren't targeting Windows, you may have to ask the user to manually fix his firewall software.

Oh shameless plug.  You can use this [open source STUN server and client library](http://www.stunprotocol.org) which supports all of the semantics described above. Follow up with me offline if you need access to a stun service.

Comment: Interested as to your recommendations regarding a stun service. You mentioned following up offline, but looking at your profile, I'm not seeing a way to message you directly.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this article useful

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364726%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

I would start with each os and ask if firewall services are turned on.  Secondly, I would attempt the socket connections and determine from the error codes if connections are being reset or timeout.  I'm only familiar with winsock coding, so I can't really say much for Linux or mac os.

Comment: Ah, I see what you were getting at now. Unfortunately, the case I'm most concerned about is if a connection is behind a hardware firewall, such as a home router. I've already set up my app so that it requests an exception from Windows Firewall.

Comment: In that case, your only option is to attempt to make the socket connection and read the socket status messages ;)